# login shell for proxy(ssh-D) access only?

Tags: security, shell, ssh

I want create an user in remote host(e.g. proxy.example.com), is there something Restricted login shell like git-shell for proxy-only ssh access?

Comment: You might have some luck with the `ChrootDirectory` config: http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/121/503450/30/570/threaded

Answer (score 1):

Write your own! `restricted-shell.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("You are now connected to the proxy. Press enter to exit.\n");
  scanf("*c");
  exit(0);
}
```